# Using a Logic App Condition To Compare Multiple Values From The Same Field

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am trying to setup a condition that compares multiple values in a field. So if the field contains 1,2 3 do this otherwise do something else. As shown in the attached image. However this only goes false if the field contains the first value. If the second or third value is contained it goes true. How can I make it false for all three values?

[image]

Comment: Can I know what data type are you checking for?

Comment: Dynamics 365 Optionset values